# How to read json file using rapidjson and output to std::string?

Tags: c++, rapidjson

How can I read a `*.json` file and put the output on a `std::string`?

I have this sample, but I always get `null` on `std::string`.

```
#include <rapidjson/document.h>
#include <rapidjson/istreamwrapper.h>
#include "rapidjson/writer.h"
#include "rapidjson/stringbuffer.h"
#include <rapidjson/ostreamwrapper.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace rapidjson;
using namespace std;

void main()
{
    ifstream ifs("input.json");
    IStreamWrapper isw(ifs);
    Document d;
    d.ParseStream(isw);

    StringBuffer buffer;
    Writer<StringBuffer> writer(buffer);
    d.Accept(writer);

    std::string jsonStr(buffer.GetString());
    if(jsonStr == "null")
        std::cout << "is null..." << std::endl; //<--always here!
    else
    {
        std::cout << jsonStr.c_str() << std::endl;

        d["ip"] = "123456789";

        ofstream ofs("output.json");
        OStreamWrapper osw(ofs);
        Writer<OStreamWrapper> writer2(osw);
        d.Accept(writer2);
    }
}
```

This is my json file:

```
{
  "ip" :  "192.168.0.100",
  "angle x": 20,
  "angle y": 0,
  "angle z": 0
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve exactly? If you want to read the whole file into `string`, you don't need a rapidjson for that.

Comment: I want to read from a file, change some fields on json, write back to another file.

Comment: @waas1919: What does your file `input.json` contain? Post the minimal valid JSON here. Did you validate that your parsing is successful with [HasParseError()](http://rapidjson.org/classrapidjson_1_1_generic_document.html#a7607bb42b51547e44bfd4cab35d8f20e) and [GetParseError()](http://rapidjson.org/classrapidjson_1_1_generic_document.html#ab94c280c079a6837a24951cb4d8f337b)?

Comment: @Azeem thanks for the comment. I've added my json file.

Comment: @Azeem d.GetParseError(); and d.HasParseError() doesnt return any errors. I guess the problem is on passing to the string...

Comment: @waas1919: Can you print `buffer.GetString()` before getting an `std::string` from it? What does it print?

Comment: @waas1919: I played around with RapidJSON and your code works perfectly. Here's the [example](https://gist.github.com/iamAzeem/0a1feb4e8104b8970b26767ef344d23e) that I worked with. Make sure that there's not any other detail that you are missing.

Comment: @Azeem Thanks! You were correct. Can you write your last comment as the answer for this thread so I can close. The buffer.GetString() was indeed showing that the file was empty and it was printing nothing. I screw up somewhere and didn't notice that the file was wrong. Your clues were very helpful :)

Comment: @waas1919: You are welcome! :) I'm glad that it helped. I've posted the code as answer with explanation.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need to check for all the errors before converting to `std::string`. Make sure that the file is open for reading / writing and the parsing is successful i.e. the JSON is valid. `GetParseError()` and `GetErrorOffset()` are the functions to validate parsing.

I've used your example and enhanced it. Hope you won't mind. :-)

Here's a working [example](https://gist.github.com/iamAzeem/0a1feb4e8104b8970b26767ef344d23e):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <rapidjson/document.h>
#include <rapidjson/istreamwrapper.h>
#include <rapidjson/writer.h>
#include <rapidjson/stringbuffer.h>
#include <rapidjson/ostreamwrapper.h>

int main()
{
    using namespace rapidjson;

    std::ifstream ifs { R"(C:\Test\Test.json)" };
    if ( !ifs.is_open() )
    {
        std::cerr << "Could not open file for reading!\n";
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    IStreamWrapper isw { ifs };

    Document doc {};
    doc.ParseStream( isw );

    StringBuffer buffer {};
    Writer<StringBuffer> writer { buffer };
    doc.Accept( writer );

    if ( doc.HasParseError() )
    {
        std::cout << "Error  : " << doc.GetParseError()  << '\n'
                  << "Offset : " << doc.GetErrorOffset() << '\n';
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    const std::string jsonStr { buffer.GetString() };

    std::cout << jsonStr << '\n';

    doc[ "ip" ] = "127.0.0.1";

    std::ofstream ofs { R"(C:\Test\NewTest.json)" };
    if ( !ofs.is_open() )
    {
        std::cerr << "Could not open file for writing!\n";
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    OStreamWrapper osw { ofs };
    Writer<OStreamWrapper> writer2 { osw };
    doc.Accept( writer2 );

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```