# How to use rapidjson library in my c++ code?

Tags: c++, json, header-files, rapidjson

Actually I am trying to parse a json file using rapidjson library . But when i am trying to add this header file in my code it shows me an error like this

```
"[Error] rapidjson/document.h: No such file or directory" and

"recipe for target 'main_1.o' failed"
```

here main_1 is my file name.
This is my actual code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include "rapidjson/document.h"

using namespace rapidjson;

Document document;
document.Parse(json);

int main()
{
    char name[50];
    int t_value;
    return 0;
    
}
```

And also i haven't idea about where i want to add my json file?

But i really don't know where i did a mistake? please anyone help me.

Comment: *How* did you install rapidjson? *Where* did you install it?

Comment: Also remember that you can't have general statements outside of functions. It seem you might need to take a couple of steps back and go over some of the basics of C again.

Comment: Please show how you are building the code. Is it a Makefile? Direct compiler commands? Also, state where `rapidjson` has been installed. For starters, `document.Parse(json);` is invalid as C doesn't allow such expressions outside a function - can only be variable declarations, intialisations and function definitions and function prototypes.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude  Actually i didn't install any rapidjson library.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude    Actually i didn't install any rapidjson library.Actually i want to practice with parsing json files using c language.Is it possible? If you feel free please tell me what i want to install and where? In c it is not possible means can i do it in c++?

Comment: `#include` is looking for a source file. Download RapidJSON here: https://github.com/Tencent/rapidjson/releases/tag/v1.1.0 , then copy the contents of include/rapidjson into your project so they can be found. Since RapidJSON is header-only, it should just work as long as the files are in the right place.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly check the below link for installation of json, you can also visit rapidjson official website

[RapidJson installation](https://cppsecrets.com/users/285511211497106971071169711810511097121121971009711864103109971051084699111109/C00-RapidJSON-Installation.php)

And for your code:
Download all header files of rapidjson and keep it inside your current folder under rapidjson folder(new folder)

Write the below code inside main, compiler error will occur due to this.

```
Document document;
document.Parse(json);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Ubuntu then package manager can be used to install the rapidjson lib

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install rapidjson-dev
```

The path of the rapidjson include for me was

```
/usr/include/rapidjson
```

and in the cpp/hpp file

```
#include <rapidjson/document.h>
```

worked for me

sample program to load file

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>

#include <rapidjson/document.h>
#include <rapidjson/istreamwrapper.h>
#include <rapidjson/writer.h>
#include <rapidjson/stringbuffer.h>
#include <rapidjson/ostreamwrapper.h>

int main()
{

    using namespace rapidjson;

    std::ifstream ifs { R"(myfile.json)" };
    if ( !ifs.is_open() )
    {
        std::cerr << "Could not open file for reading!\n";
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    IStreamWrapper isw { ifs };

    Document doc {};
    doc.ParseStream( isw );

    StringBuffer buffer {};
    Writer<StringBuffer> writer { buffer };
    doc.Accept( writer );

    if ( doc.HasParseError() )
    {
        std::cout << "Error  : " << doc.GetParseError()  << '\n'
                  << "Offset : " << doc.GetErrorOffset() << '\n';
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    const std::string jsonStr { buffer.GetString() };

    std::cout << jsonStr << '\n';



    std::cout <<"done\n";
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Demo code Source:
[How to read json file using rapidjson and output to std::string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45248182/how-to-read-json-file-using-rapidjson-and-output-to-stdstring)