# What is the easiest way to parse a json file using rapidjson?

Tags: c++, json, parsing, rapidjson

So I am just getting familiar with `rapidjson.h` but I can't find this one basic piece of example code of parsing the `*.json` file.

I found the official [turorial][1].
But here however they parse the json stored in a C string. I know how this string is supposed to look like but I'm lazy to make a custom Parser just to convert my file to this string. I mean I was kinda hoping that rapidjson is supposed to do that for me. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

The closest thing I found to what I need is here [How to read json file using rapidjson and output to std::string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45248182/how-to-read-json-file-using-rapidjson-and-output-to-stdstring)

Therefore I was really surprised that I can't just do something like this (with `*.json` file being in the same folder as my program):

```
rapidjson::Document d;
d.Parse("myJson.json");
```

### My 1. question is:

Do I have to use `std::ifstream` and `rapidjson::IStreamWrapper` to get my `Document` like in the example above and what other as simple as possible alternatives there are?

My 2. question is: (this one would be much easier to ask if i could comment the post above)

What does the `R` mean in `std::ifstream ifs { R"(C:\Test\Test.json)" };` and how
do I change the `C:\Test\Test.json` string to `const char*` variable?

Because this isn't working.

```
const char* str = "C:\Test\Test.json";
std::ifstream ifs { R"(str)" }; //error
std::ifstream ifs { R(str) }; //error
std::ifstream ifs{ (str) }; //ok but I don't like it
```


  [1]: https://rapidjson.org/md_doc_tutorial.html

Comment: Please stick to 1 question oer question . Your "2" is nothing at all to do with json and more about how to open a file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`FileReadStream`](https://rapidjson.org/classrapidjson_1_1_file_read_stream.html) and [`ParseStream`](https://rapidjson.org/classrapidjson_1_1_generic_document.html#a3ae97682cf04685c7db9d89ebc399b85) instead of the `IStreamWrapper`. According to the documentation, `FileReadStream` is much faster than `IStreamWrapper`.

The `R` means that it's a [raw string literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal). Without it, the backslashes are interpreted as the start of [escape sequences](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape) and you would have to write it like this to make it correct:

```
"C:\\Test\\Test.json"
```

Or you could use forward slashes:

```
"C:/Test/Test.json"
```